# R - Remove dashes from a column with phone numbers

Tags: regex, r, string-substitution

I'd like to create a new column of phone numbers with no dashes. I have data that is a mix of just numbers and some numbers with dashes. The data looks as follows:

**Phone**
555-555-5555
1234567890
555-3456789
222-222-2222
51318312491

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since you are dealing with a very straightforward substitution, you can easily use `gsub` to find the character you want to remove and replace it with nothing.

Assuming your dataset is called "mydf" and the column of interest is "Phone", try this:

```
gsub("-", "", mydf$Phone)
```

Answer (score 6):

Building on the answer of @Ananda Mahto, it seemed useful to show how to break the numbers up again and put a parenthetical around the area code.

```
phone <- c("1234567890", "555-3456789", "222-222-2222", "5131831249")
phone <- gsub("-", "", phone)
gsub("(^\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{4}$)", "(\\1) \\2 \\3", phone)
[1] "(123) 456 7890" "(555) 345 6789" "(222) 222 2222" "(513) 183 1249"
```

The second regex creates three capture groups, two with three digits and the final one with four.  Then R substitutes them back in with a space between each and (  ) around the first one.  You could also put hyphens between capture group 2 and capture group 3. [Not sure at all why Skype appeared out of nowhere!]